# How to make the sample run Open CV

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, opencv, augmented-reality

I am trying to make Open CV project sample for Template Matching as explained [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) .
Steps i did so far includes :

[Downloaded](http://opencv.org/) and imported Open CV framework in my project changed the .m extension files to .mm and in the .pch file i have included the code

```
 #ifdef __cplusplus
 #import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
 #endif

 #ifdef __OBJC__
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 #endif
```

I have also downloaded and imported the MatchTemplate_Demo.cpp file from the [link](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html).
But here having library linking issue

```
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/G1/Desktop/Xcode'
   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-Lprojects/FirstOpenCv/opencv/lib/debug'
   ld: library not found for -lopencv_calib3d
   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I followed the same step to include the library as given [here](http://computer-vision-talks.com/2012/06/opencv-tutorial-a-collection-of-opencv-samples-for-iphoneipad-part-1/).

```
2) Add $(SRCROOT)/opencv to header search path and $(SRCROOT)/opencv/lib/debug for library search path for debug configuration and $(SRCROOT)/opencv/lib/release for release build.

3) Add OpenCV libs to linker input by modifying "Other Linker Flags" option with "-lopencv_calib3d -lzlib -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_video -lopencv_core".
```

Now can please any one tell me how should i make the project run.
I have taken the source and template image and imported in the project.

[image]

[image]

I have basically ViewController.h and ViewController.mm file now i don't know what should i code in these files to see the result.

[image]

Also Step 2 :
I need to scan the image in real time using camera view (so that when i place my camera over the source image it should scan and find the template).

On following this [link](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/hello/hello.html#opencvioshelloworld) i got Linker error while importing the .cpp [file](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) :

```
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386 clang:
error: linker command failed with exit    code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please can any one suggest me how should i implement it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have three interrelated questions here:

1/ how to get openCV framework to run in an iOS project
2/ how to get the Template Matching c++ sample code to run in an iOS project
3/ how to do live template matching with the camera view

**1/ how to get openCV framework to run in an iOS project**

- Download and import the openCV framework as you describe
- Change the .pch file as you describe
- check that c++ standard library is set to libc++ in your target build settings (this is the default for new projects)
- *Don't* just import demo.cpp without making changes as described below (it is a 'raw' c++ progam with it's own `main` function, and needs alterations to work as part of an iOS/Cocoa project).
- *Don't* mess with header search paths, other linker flags etc, this isn't necessary if you have imported the prebuilt framework from openCV.org.
- *Don't* change your .m files to .mm unless you know that you need to. My advice is to keep your c++ code separate from your objective-C code as far as practicable, so most of you files should be .m files (objective-C) or .cpp files (c++). You only need .mm prefixes for "objective-C++" where you intend to mix objective-C and c++ in the same file.

**2/ how to get the Template Matching c++ sample code to run in an iOS project**

We are going to set this up so that your iOS viewController - and the bulk of your iOS code - does not need to know that the image is processed using openCV/C++, and likewise the C++ code doesn't need to know where it's input or output image data is being routed to. We do this by making a small wrapper class between the two that translates objective-C method calls to c++ class member functions and back. We will also set up a category on UIImage to translate image formats from iOS-friendly UIImage to openCV-native cv::Mat.

*UIImage+OpenCV Category*

You need some utility methods to convert from UIImage to cv::Mat and back. A good place to put these is in a UIImage category. In XCode: *File>New FIle>Cocoa Touch>Objective-C category* will set you up. Call the category *OpenCV* and make it a category on *UIImage*. This .m file you will want to change to .mm as it will need to understand c++ types from the openCV framework.

The header should look something like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (OpenCV)

    //cv::Mat to UIImage
+ (UIImage *)imageWithCVMat:(const cv::Mat&)cvMat;

    //UIImage to cv::Mat
- (cv::Mat)cvMat;

@end
```

The .mm file should implement these methods by closely following [this openCV.org code sample](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html#opencviosimagemanipulation) adapted to work as category methods (eg you don't pass a UIImage into the instance method, but refer to it using `self`).

You can use the category methods as if they are UIImage class and instance methods like this:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCVMat:matImage];  //class method

cv::Mat matImage = [image cvMat];  //instance method
```

*openCV wrapper class*

Make a wrapper class to convert your objective-C method (called from a viewController) to a c++ function

header something like this

```
//  CVWrapper.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CVWrapper : NSObject

+ (NSImage*) templateMatchImage:(UIImage*)image
                          patch:(UIImage*)patch
                         method:(int)method;
@end
```

We send in the template image, patch image and template matching method, and get back an image showing the match

implementation  (.mm file)

```
//  CVWrapper.mm
#import "CVWrapper.h"
#import "CVTemplateMatch.h"
#import "UIImage+OpenCV.h"

@implementation CVWrapper


+ (UIImage*) templateMatchImage:(UIImage *)image
                          patch:(UIImage *)patch
                         method:(int)method
{
    cv::Mat imageMat = [image cvMat];
    cv::Mat patchMat = [patch cvMat];

    cv::Mat matchImage = 
           CVTemplateMatch::matchImage(imageMat, 
                                        patchMat,
                                        method);

    UIImage* result =  [UIImage imageWithCVMat:matchImage];
    return result;
}
```

We are effectively taking a standard objective-C method and UIImage types and translating them into a call to a C++ member function with c++(openCV framework) types, and translating the result back to a UIImage.

*C++ TemplateMatch class*

Header:

```
//  TemplateMatch.h

#ifndef __CVOpenTemplate__CVTemplateMatch__
#define __CVOpenTemplate__CVTemplateMatch__

class CVTemplateMatch
{
public:
    static cv::Mat matchImage (cv::Mat imageMat,
                               cv::Mat patchMat, 
                               int method);
};

#endif /* defined(__CVOpenTemplate__CVTemplateMatch__) */


@end
```

Implementation:

This is the Template Match openCV example code, reworked as a class implementation:

```
//  TemplateMatch.cpp
/*
 Alterations for use in iOS project
 [1] remove GUI code (iOS supplies the GUI)
 [2] change main{} to static member function 
     with appropriate inputs and return value
 [3] change MatchingMethod{} signature 
     to return Mat value
 */

#include "CVTemplateMatch.h"

    //[1] #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

    /// Global Variables
Mat img; Mat templ; Mat result;
    //[1] char* image_window = "Source Image";
    //[1] char* result_window = "Result window";

int match_method; 
    //[1]  int max_Trackbar = 5; 

    /// Function Headers
Mat MatchingMethod( int, void* );  //[3] (added return value to function)

    // [2] /** @function main */
    // [2] int main( int argc, char** argv )

Mat CVTemplateMatch::matchImage (Mat image,Mat patch, int method)
    // [2]
{
        /// Load image and template
        //[2]  img = imread( argv[1], 1 );
        //[2] templ = imread( argv[2], 1 );

    img = image;           //[2]
    templ = patch;         //[2]
    match_method = method; //[2]

        /// Create windows
        //[1] namedWindow( image_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
        //[1] namedWindow( result_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

        /// Create Trackbar
        //[1] char* trackbar_label = "Method: \n 0: SQDIFF \n 1: SQDIFF NORMED \n 2: TM CCORR \n 3: TM CCORR NORMED \n 4: TM COEFF \n 5: TM COEFF NORMED";
        //[1] createTrackbar( trackbar_label, image_window, &match_method, max_Trackbar, MatchingMethod );

    Mat result = MatchingMethod( 0, 0 );

        //[1] waitKey(0);
        //[2] return 0;
    return result;  //[2]
}


    //[3] void MatchingMethod( int, void* )
Mat MatchingMethod( int, void* )

{
        /// Source image to display
    Mat img_display;
    img.copyTo( img_display );

        /// Create the result matrix
    int result_cols =  img.cols - templ.cols + 1;
    int result_rows = img.rows - templ.rows + 1;

    result.create( result_cols, result_rows, CV_32FC1 );

        /// Do the Matching and Normalize
    matchTemplate( img, templ, result, match_method );
    normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

        /// Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
    double minVal; double maxVal; Point minLoc; Point maxLoc;
    Point matchLoc;

    minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat() );

        /// For SQDIFF and SQDIFF_NORMED, the best matches are lower values. For all the other methods, the higher the better
    if( match_method  == CV_TM_SQDIFF || match_method == CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED )
        { matchLoc = minLoc; }
    else
        { matchLoc = maxLoc; }

        /// Show me what you got
    rectangle( img_display, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols , matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0 );
    rectangle( result, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols , matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0 );

        //[1]  imshow( image_window, img_display );  
        //[1] imshow( result_window, result );       

    return img_display; //[3] add return value
}
```

Now in your `viewController` you just need to call this method:

```
UIImage* matchedImage = 
       [CVWrapper templateMatchImage:self.imageView.image
                               patch:self.patchView.image
                              method:0];
```

with no c++ in sight.

**3/ Template Matching with live camera view**

The short answer: `matchTemplate` is not going to work too well in a live camera context. The algorithm is looking for a match in the image with the same scale and orientation as the patch: it slides the patch tile across the image at it's original orientation and size comparing for best match. This is not going to yield great results if the image is perspective-skewed, a different size or rotated to a different orientation.

You could  look instead at OpenCV's [Feature Detection algorithms](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/features2d.html), some of which have been [moved to non-free](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/nonfree.html). Here is a [nice description of SIFT](http://www.aishack.in/2010/05/sift-scale-invariant-feature-transform/) to give you the idea. For video capture you might also want to look at `cap_ios.h` in `opencv2/highgui`: [here is a tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html#opencviosvideoprocessing).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have downloaded already compiled library so no need to follow the steps that you have mentioned in your question and this the issues(i.e. you have followed incorrect steps) because that steps are to compile the source code into static library.

Follow the below steps and it will be done

- Unzip the downloaded framework. You can see folder with name "opencv2.framework"
- Drag that folder directly into project(Note. When you drag that folder into xcode, xcode will prompt you dialog there will be a tick mark to actually copy this into folder. please tick that check box)
- In you .pch file import openCV like you have mentioned in your question is correct way

  Now compile. 
  One thing more wherever you want to use function of openCV that file should have .mm extension(i.e. Objective C++ source) It will run perfectly. 
  [Help link:](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/hello/hello.html#opencvioshelloworld)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @lducool , the Help Link you gaved me is working just fine but when i imported the Template Matching(http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) .cpp file in the project it gives out linker error ... How should i resolve this issue ?

Comment: ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: why are you trying to import that file. That file might be already included in openCV framework. Try to check it out.

Comment: I am trying to import that file to make a sample for template matching also I have checked the files in the framework, that file is not present in the framework ...

Comment: I just tried to include that file and removed unnecessary or not compatible statments from that file and it's working fine.

Comment: Can you please put those statements here .. so that i can do the same and see if it works for me ..

Comment: Please paste your all errors in questions so I can edit my answer

Comment: I have edited my answer with the error that i was getting during implementation of the sample ...

Comment: @lducool can you please include those statements in your answer now ?